# How to solve this problem about $\operatorname{SL_2}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The problem is:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix},$
$B=\begin{bmatrix} 0& 1\\ -1& 0\end{bmatrix},$

$\forall C\in \operatorname{SL_2}(\mathbb{Z}),$
$\exists C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n\in \{A, B, A^{-1}\},$

$s.t. C=C_1 C_2\dots C_n$

So far I have found that $B^3=B^{-1}$, which means that the problem is equivalent with

$\operatorname{SL_2}(\mathbb{Z})=\left \langle A, B\right \rangle$

But I think that I am still far from actually solving it.

Comment: Your definition of $SO_2(\Bbb Z)$ must be different from mine.